# Пользовательский ввод в Java

Tags: java

Всем привет, учусь писать на Java, не могу понять в чем проблема.. Программа корректно работает с целым числом, но при вводе десятичного выводит ошибки. Помогите новичку.

```
import java.util.Scanner;введите сюда код

public class MoonWeight {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double moon;
        double weight;
        weight = 0;

        System.out.println
                ("Сила тяжести на Луне составляет около 17%. Напишите программу, которая вычисляет Ваш вес на Луне.");
        System.out.print
                ("Введите Ваш вес: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        weight = scan.nextDouble();
        moon = weight * 0.17;
        System.out.println
                ("Ваш вес " + weight + " кг. составляет на Луне " + moon + " кг.");
    }
}
```

Ошибки при вводе десятичного значения:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
at od.ua.hillel.MoonWeight.main(MoonWeight.java:17)
```

Comment: какой формат десятичного числа вы вводите?

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы вводите число с точкой. Попробуйте тогда с запятой (1,0) - должно отработать без ошибок.

Comment: Большое спасибо всем кто откликнулся, проблема решилась благодаря вашим советам!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны точно определить язык для своего сканера.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17150679/4444092)

Comment: Это необязательно. Просто нужно использовать разделитель, соответствующий текущей локали.